# Totally misunderstanding how a PMOS works? PMOS not turning off

Tags: mosfet, gpio, pmos, rotary-encoder

I'm trying to use a PMOS to inverse an on/off signal. This is for a battery powered application.
VSNS pin is connected to MCU GPIO. By design the rotary encoder channels A/B (detent type) are always HIGH when it's not being operated. Input is 3.3V.

- User stops using encoder, MCU sleeps
- The high signal on channel A get translated to LOW, MCU stays off
- User turns encoder (any direction), PMOS conducts and MCU wakes on next HIGH

My understanding of a PMOS is that:

- The GATE voltage needs to be (source voltage - specified Vgs threshold
  voltage) for the current to flow from source to drain.
- If GATE is same voltage as SOURCE, current should not flow.

To confirm this, I tried a PMOS with a Vgs(TH) of -2v max (DMP3050LVT-7) with Q10 and LED10 part of circuit and it always seems to be showing voltage present on drain (about 1.6v with led attached and almost source voltage (3.3v) with no load. LED is faintly lit normally and pressing the button (SW2) lights up LED fully.

I thought maybe it's a faulty part. Tried 2 more, same thing. Bad batch? Ordered even lower Vgs parts like DMP2004K and Si2377EDS, Vgs(TH) of-1v max. Observed same behaviors.

Is this just leakage current or I don't understand how a PMOS works, any further clarification would be really helpful.

There is no way these are all faulty parts.

[image]

Comment: Your understanding is right.   If the gate=source, no current should flow.   Noted these are all SMT parts.  Take off your blinders that this is a component/circuit design problem and start suspecting your PCB layout or something "physical".   I've diagnosed many inexplicable problems by use of optical magnification.   Note it doesn't take much current to dimly light an LED.   Is your board clean?  (You got all the solder residue off?)  R U sure you got the pin-out of the mosfet in your layout correct???

Comment: Good to know. I tried the led/switch part of circuit on a breadboard with SOT-23 breakout boards for simplicity's sake/minimize potential errors. I have tried 3 different part numbers already. Will try optical magnification.

Comment: Try shorting source-gate with a wire instead of a 10k resistor... see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you *certain* that you have the right pinout for your FETs, and you didn't swap the drain and source?

Comment: Incidentally, your understanding of how a PMOS works isn't quite right: applying exactly the threshold voltage will only get you a tiny amount of current. You need to apply more than the threshold voltage (a more negative voltage in the case of a P-channel device) to get the FET to turn fully on. Look in the datasheet for what gate-source voltage the Rds,on is specified at, and try to use that voltage or greater. In other words, the DMP3050, only specified at -4.5 V, isn't suitable for 3.3 V drive (but would probably work here anyway). The DMP2004 and Si2377 are fine though.

Comment: I have tried both swapping drain and source and without a resistor (source-gate). Still no go.

Comment: Added a 10k resistor to drain parallel to LED anode and it finally reads 0v at drain. There is some quiescent current at drain but changing to 100k resistor brought it to a reasonable amount, about 5ua.